# 3D Gamma function

Tags: plotting, special-functions, precision-and-accuracy

I try to plot the following function:

```
Plot3D[Gamma[1+0.5*(n+m)]/Sqrt[Gamma[1+n]*Gamma[1+m]],{n,0,1000},{m,0,1000}]
```

I expect that for m=n and near to it the value should be equal to 1. 
This is true but not for a particular range of m and n. See [WA response](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28Gamma%281%2B%28x%2BT%29%2F2%29%2Fsqrt%28Gamma%281%2Bx%29Gamma%281%2BT%29%29%29++x%3D0+to+1000+T%3D0+to+1000) for query

```
plot (Gamma(1+(x+T)/2)/sqrt(Gamma(1+x)Gamma(1+T)))  x=0 to 1000 T=0 to 1000
```

Is it possible that in this range the function is equal to one ONLY for m=n and so the plot3d can not be able to resolve the maximum ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I am guessing, comparing your MMA code with your WA code that you meant Sqrt[Gamma[1+n]*Gamma[1+m]] instead of Sqrt[Gamma[1+n]*Gamma[1+n]]

Comment: @Bill you was right I made a type error and I correct it. Thanks, but the problem persist .

Comment: Another possible workaround would be to reformulate your function entirely in terms of `LogGamma[]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Gamma` is an extremely quickly increasing function, so you're dealing with the ratio of huge numbers here.  Something similar to [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) can happen.

Fortunately, Mathematica is very good at dealing with this situation if you let it use arbitrary precision instead of machine precision.  Change `0.5` to `1/2` and add something like `WorkingPrecision -> 30`.

```
Plot3D[Gamma[1 + (n + m)/2]/Sqrt[Gamma[1 + n]*Gamma[1 + m]], {n, 0, 
  1000}, {m, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 9):

While @Szabolcs has provided the correct work-around, the actual issue has to do with automatic use of `Compile` for function evaluation. The affected range is such that the value of `Gamma[1+n]` is still a machine real, but their product is out-of-bound.

The issue comes, because the default setting of `Compile`'s `RuntimeOptions` is to [tolerate machine arithmetic underflows](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuntimeOptions.html?q=RuntimeOptions#145081921).

```
(* In[48]:= *)Compile[{{a, _Real}, {n, _Real}, {m, _Real}}, {a, 
   1/Sqrt[n m]}][Gamma[1 + 116.], Gamma[1 + 115.], Gamma[1 + 117.]]

(* Out[48]= {3.39311*10^190, 0.} *)
```

Product of such numbers gives zero. The work-around is to either use extended precision, as suggested by @Szabolcs, or to avoid using `Compile`:

```
Plot3D[Divide[Gamma[1 + (m + n)/2], 
  Sqrt[Gamma[m + 1] Gamma[n + 1]]], {m, 0, 1000}, {n, 0, 1000}, 
 Compiled -> False, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `Compiled` option, thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

As I've previously noted, when computing functions that involve ratios of gamma functions, it is manifestly better to re-express in terms of `LogGamma[]` and then do a final exponentiation afterwards. This deftly sidesteps the issue of huge intermediate values being used to compute a modestly-sized result.

```
Plot3D[Exp[LogGamma[1 + (n + m)/2] - (LogGamma[1 + n] + LogGamma[1 + m])/2],
       {n, 0, 1000}, {m, 0, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot of a ratio of gamma functions]